Kids tv series with tiny humans (2 men, 1 woman)
It seems a British one, not sure though. The story is about some kids who got acquainted with 3 thumb-sized adults (2 men and 1 woman).
Another episode I could remember is those tiny characters took a small toy boat/ship to get somewhere but then at the end of the episode returned back.
It was around the late 80's but that depends, it aired late in my country. It's live action, old British style (may not be British) appearance in clothes. I think one of the characters was fat and dumpy and the other slim one was funny. Another aspect is that the thumb-sized people were hiding all the time from elders and known only to these kids, I think.
Trying to look it up, please advise. 

Approximate year? Animated or live action? (And do you remember anything else? About their appearance, perhaps?)

it was in late 80's something but that depends, it aired late in my country, it's live action, old british style (may not be british) appearance in clothes, I think one of the characters was fat and dump and the other slim one was funny.

another aspect is that the thumb size people were hiding all the time from elders and known only to these kids I think... and one time there was some doll house too where they lived...

they were small in size (about thumb) but from age they were grown up people.

Thanks, added. There's always The Borrowers, but it's from 1992 and they were 2 females and 1 male. (They did have a boat in the 1993 sequel, though)

interesting reference but it's not, the female character is a child in it but they all were grown up people, also the boat was a real deal, looked real even if it was small and had wheel which they were using to steer around, something similar to http://wallpapersinhq.pw/84576-old_sailboat/

Maybe it's from 70's aired in 80's in my country, timing can't be estimated but it's old

it's a pity that I couldn't find it in this exhaustive list https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/1ycrjg/anyone_know_of_any_movies_featuring_tiny_people/

@Walt please review

God, I actually know this one and loved it way back when, but completely blanked out on it (as per usual). I even remember the theme music! Thanks for that bit of nostalgia, and glad you found it. :)

yeah it was a long anguish, glad to finally know it. Not so much lucky with youtube links, do you have any?

Me neither, but you can see a short promo for it here.

The Return of the Antelope was a UK TV series aired on ITV between 1986 and 1988. It was a children's fantasy series about two English children, circa 1899, who befriend a group of shipwrecked Lilliputians.
from wikipedia
Return of the Antelope on Amazon: 
There is not much on google about it, if you find any online episodes then let us know!

kindly use edit button to improve your answer and don't give lots of incomplete answers.

Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the monthly answer challenge.
